# Call External WebService using multiple Threads with .NET

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, asynchronous, parallel.foreach

I'm new to Parallel programming but I've searched a lot of blogs and other sites (including SO) to achieve the following: I need to call an external webservice (which I don't have code access) multiple times. Every call takes about 10 seconds to process so I decided to use Parallel to gain performance.

```
    public BlockingCollection<TransacaoResponse> ExecutarAsync(TransacaoRequest request)
    {
        BlockingCollection<TransacaoResponse> listResponse = new BlockingCollection<TransacaoResponse>();
        Parallel.ForEach<Item>(request.Itens, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, (c) =>
        {
            TransacaoResponse responseInner = new TransacaoResponse();
            int result = _operadora.EnviarTransacao(request.Codigo);
            responseInner.Status = result;
            listResponse.Add(responseInner);
        });
        return listResponse;
    }
```

even using Parallel.ForEach and BlockingCollection, it's taking 50 secs to return the result (I tested calling this method 5 times), the same time comparing to standard Foreach. What am I missing? Is there a bottleneck within this code? Thanks.

Comment: What is 'EnviarTransacao' are there any locks inside that method or submethods?

Comment: EnviarTransacao is the webservice that I'm calling, I just have a reference to it in my application, so it's a blackbox to me.

Comment: Well, other than the Add to the List, there isnt any blocking code. Maybe you need to duplicate your request-Paremeter-object aswell. Or try decompile with tools like DotPeek and find out where the blocking happens.

Comment: But even if I don't know the implementation of the webservice, It's not supposed that the Parallel.ForEach takes care of the parallelism?

Comment: It does, but there is still code where threads can only pass at once, like lock-Statements for example. My guess here is that the external service doesnt process requests from same ip/user/context whatever parallel and therefor you probably need to duplicate that requestobject. You might need to duplicate everything that is involved in the request. One wild guess here is that your network connection is the actual bottleneck.

Comment: when you say "duplicate request", you mean: TransacaoRequest request2 = new TransacaoRequest();
                request2 = request;  , inside the loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96275/discussion-between-danilo-ruziska-and-csharpie).